# Where can I find geodata on livestock densities?

Tags: data

I am currently looking for geodata that represents livestocks (cattle, pig, poultry) at most detailed resolution for France. Up to now, the best data I was able to find is the FAO's GLOBAL LIVESTOCK DENSITIES (census data) data ([See FAO data](http://www.fao.org/AG/AGAInfo/resources/en/glw/GLW_dens.html)).

For France, the raster has an resolution that is around 3.6km. Does anyone know a better and free to use/not that expensive source? I would be also willing to geocode a livestock farms dataset or something like that.

Comment: International Livestock Research Institute (ILRI) Global GIS Datasets http://192.156.137.110/gis/bylocation.asp

Comment: As much as I can see, they only offer data for India and Eastern Africa.